# servicestack auth is failing with 502

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, servicestack

I upgraded to servicestack from 5.4.1 to 5.6.0 and now my service in azure is locking up and will not allow users to login.  If I restart the service it works util some point they receive an error. After that they cannot login until we restart the service.

When I call this link it fails with 502. Does anyone know of an issue with version 5.6.0. or have any ideas about troubleshooting this?

```
https://AZURE SERVER/auth/credentials: 502 Bad Gateway
```

Its[image] even failing badly in postman

Server Logs It's not really telling me anything

```
#Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 8.0
#Fields: date time s-sitename cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) cs(Cookie) cs(Referer) cs-host sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status sc-bytes cs-bytes time-taken
2019-12-12 22:00:00 CBWSERVICESDEV POST /json/reply/Authenticate X-ARR-LOG-ID=475c0eee-3de5-44fd-9bb4-fcc04f10208c 443 - 104.43.246.4 ServiceStack+.NET+Client+5.60 - - **myURLIDOntWantPublic** 502 3 12029 405 1229 15
2019-12-12 22:00:00 CBWSERVICESDEV POST /json/reply/Authenticate X-ARR-LOG-ID=8ec16510-6c04-447a-aac6-d7fbd21246b8 443 - 104.43.246.4 ServiceStack+.NET+Client+5.60 - - **myURLIDOntWantPublic** 502 3 12029 405 1229 0
2019-12-12 22:00:30 CBWSERVICESDEV POST /json/reply/Authenticate X-ARR-LOG-ID=cc89a2c9-9fd9-4e56-9709-6fc5292bf2bd 443 - 104.43.246.4 ServiceStack+.NET+Client+5.60 - - **myURLIDOntWantPublic** 502 3 12029 405 1229 12
2019-12-12 22:00:59 CBWSERVICESDEV POST /json/reply/Authenticate X-ARR-LOG-ID=e2d1b74b-fb9b-40ac-b89e-8217a1cd2cc6 443 - 104.43.246.4 ServiceStack+.NET+Client+5.60 - - **myURLIDOntWantPublic** 502 3 12029 405 1229 31
2019-12-12 22:00:59 CBWSERVICESDEV POST /json/reply/Authenticate X-ARR-LOG-ID=32836823-b0b7-402f-8893-4f1eca87c2a6 443 - 104.43.246.4 ServiceStack+.NET+Client+5.60 - - **myURLIDOntWantPublic** 502 3 12029 405 1229 31
2019-12-12 22:00:59 CBWSERVICESDEV POST /json/reply/Authenticate X-ARR-LOG-ID=d370c8b6-7aa6-4053-81b4-d62e260487bd 443 - 104.43.246.4 ServiceStack+.NET+Client+5.60 - - **myURLIDOntWantPublic** 502 3 12029 405 1229 62
2019-12-12 22:00:59 CBWSERVICESDEV POST /json/reply/Authenticate X-ARR-LOG-ID=ea518b6c-d69a-401a-b433-0d6c0386aed6 443 - 104.43.246.4 ServiceStack+.NET+Client+5.60 - - **myURLIDOntWantPublic** 502 3 12029 405 1229 15
2019-12-12 22:00:59 CBWSERVICESDEV POST /json/reply/Authenticate X-ARR-LOG-ID=1fee66b8-665c-4300-b73f-66e28a0b375a 443 - 104.43.246.4 ServiceStack+.NET+Client+5.60 - - **myURLIDOntWantPublic** 502 3 12029 405 1229 46
2019-12-12 22:00:59 CBWSERVICESDEV POST /json/reply/Authenticate X-ARR-LOG-ID=59e516a2-6138-4961-9776-d56766fb32fd 443 - 104.43.246.4 ServiceStack+.NET+Client+5.60 - - **myURLIDOntWantPublic** 502 3 12029 405 1229 15
2019-12-12 22:00:59 CBWSERVICESDEV POST /json/reply/Authenticate X-ARR-LOG-ID=bd28d763-d89b-473e-9f02-a99bf5940fce 443 - 104.43.246.4 ServiceStack+.NET+Client+5.60 - - **myURLIDOntWantPublic** 502 3 12029 405 1229 31
2019-12-12 22:00:59 CBWSERVICESDEV POST /json/reply/Authenticate X-ARR-LOG-ID=dbeceb63-a19b-44c2-b999-8be87f9e4bf6 443 - 104.43.246.4 ServiceStack+.NET+Client+5.60 - - **myURLIDOntWantPublic** 502 3 12029 405 1229 31
2019-12-12 22:01:30 CBWSERVICESDEV POST /json/reply/Authenticate X-ARR-LOG-ID=a1cec85a-670b-445b-a1cc-2c40baab6a97 443 - 104.43.246.4 ServiceStack+.NET+Client+5.60 - - **myURLIDOntWantPublic** 502 3 12029 405 1229 15
2019-12-12 22:02:00 CBWSERVICESDEV POST /json/reply/Authenticate X-ARR-LOG-ID=d2f9503f-7660-4db3-b71f-013333947819 443 - 104.43.246.4 ServiceStack+.NET+Client+5.60 - - **myURLIDOntWantPublic** 502 3 12029 405 1229 31
2019-12-12 22:02:00 CBWSERVICESDEV POST /json/reply/Authenticate X-ARR-LOG-ID=bd2ed24a-aa63-415a-a015-24c1942913e9 443 - 104.43.246.4 ServiceStack+.NET+Client+5.60 - - **myURLIDOntWantPublic** 502 3 12029 405 1229 31
2019-12-12 22:02:00 CBWSERVICESDEV POST /json/reply/Authenticate X-ARR-LOG-ID=6e5ff14d-d1cd-4b93-bfdf-5096e1eebb8c 443 - 104.43.246.4 ServiceStack+.NET+Client+5.60 - - **myURLIDOntWantPublic** 502 3 12029 405 1229 46
2019-12-12 22:02:30 CBWSERVICESDEV POST /json/reply/Authenticate X-ARR-LOG-ID=296f19c5-dd90-424c-b9cb-f20a72c79eb7 443 - 104.43.246.4 ServiceStack+.NET+Client+5.60 - - **myURLIDOntWantPublic** 502 3 12029 405 1229 12
2019-12-12 22:03:00 CBWSERVICESDEV POST /json/reply/Authenticate X-ARR-LOG-ID=d96a9920-45cf-412b-8974-913376b47152 443 - 104.43.246.4 ServiceStack+.NET+Client+5.60 - - **myURLIDOntWantPublic** 502 3 12029 405 1229 9
2019-12-12 22:03:00 CBWSERVICESDEV POST /json/reply/Authenticate X-ARR-LOG-ID=2709aebc-bce0-49ea-b899-bca3284aa41e 443 - 104.43.246.4 ServiceStack+.NET+Client+5.60 - - **myURLIDOntWantPublic** 502 3 12029 405 1229 15
2019-12-12 22:03:30 CBWSERVICESDEV POST /json/reply/Authenticate X-ARR-LOG-ID=479a53c4-ccd6-4579-a8d1-571b347ff490 443 - 104.43.246.4 ServiceStack+.NET+Client+5.60 - - **myURLIDOntWantPublic** 502 3 12029 405 1229 31
2019-12-12 22:03:54 ~1CBWSERVICESDEV GET / - 80 - 10.0.128.27 AlwaysOn - - **myURLIDOntWantPublic** 200 0 0 3107 452 31
2019-12-12 22:03:54 CBWSERVICESDEV GET / X-ARR-LOG-ID=9db78131-a89d-4fab-8593-30744b2a2ae8 80 - ::1 AlwaysOn ARRAffinity=bca9cc31b3143085a28e07db54604157e121c61665b54a8ce9a954d588f1a532 - **myURLIDOntWantPublic** 502 3 12029 405 694 15
2019-12-12 22:04:00 CBWSERVICESDEV POST /json/reply/Authenticate X-ARR-LOG-ID=fdea18e7-fdd1-49f1-80fc-dc3a816e683e 443 - 104.43.246.4 ServiceStack+.NET+Client+5.60 - - **myURLIDOntWantPublic** 502 3 12029 405 1229 15
2019-12-12 22:04:00 CBWSERVICESDEV POST /json/reply/Authenticate X-ARR-LOG-ID=5fa6e32f-0b7b-4198-9ce2-2d14593895e9 443 - 104.43.246.4 ServiceStack+.NET+Client+5.60 - - **myURLIDOntWantPublic** 502 3 12029 405 1229 15
2019-12-12 22:04:30 CBWSERVICESDEV POST /json/reply/Authenticate X-ARR-LOG-ID=cf57f29e-9879-4d68-bd5b-9f21572a8046 443 - 104.43.246.4 ServiceStack+.NET+Client+5.60 - - **myURLIDOntWantPublic** 502 3 12029 405 1229 18
2019-12-12 22:05:00 CBWSERVICESDEV POST /json/reply/Authenticate X-ARR-LOG-ID=0a5dbdab-e578-44a4-b22f-bcc6902d1c08 443 - 104.43.246.4 ServiceStack+.NET+Client+5.60 - - **myURLIDOntWantPublic** 502 3 12029 405 1229 33
2019-12-12 22:05:00 CBWSERVICESDEV POST /json/reply/Authenticate X-ARR-LOG-ID=5b14f32e-8971-46e7-b01d-e8c647e5a610 443 - 104.43.246.4 ServiceStack+.NET+Client+5.60 - - **myURLIDOntWantPublic** 502 3 12029 405 1229 17
2019-12-12 22:05:08 CBWSERVICESDEV OPTIONS /auth/credentials X-ARR-LOG-ID=d9d735e4-d0bb-4de7-95a9-08992b226216 443 - 68.118.135.78 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/79.0.3945.79+Safari/537.36 - https://cbwwebdev.azurewebsites.net/login?returnUrl=%2Fdashboard **myURLIDOntWantPublic** 200 0 0 355 1297 15
2019-12-12 22:05:08 CBWSERVICESDEV POST /auth/credentials X-ARR-LOG-ID=a4daad74-4ab1-47fc-9e3f-f1b978457d70 443 - 68.118.135.78 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/79.0.3945.79+Safari/537.36 - https://cbwwebdev.azurewebsites.net/login?returnUrl=%2Fdashboard **myURLIDOntWantPublic** 502 3 12029 471 1335 31
2019-12-12 22:05:10 CBWSERVICESDEV POST /auth/credentials X-ARR-LOG-ID=06cdb25c-a29e-4469-86ec-9d5baafe5997 443 - 68.118.135.78 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/79.0.3945.79+Safari/537.36 - https://cbwwebdev.azurewebsites.net/login?returnUrl=%2Fdashboard **myURLIDOntWantPublic** 502 3 12029 471 1335 20
2019-12-12 22:05:12 CBWSERVICESDEV POST /auth/credentials X-ARR-LOG-ID=32e2202a-c6cf-4e0c-8070-3928f8db02a6 443 - 68.118.135.78 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/79.0.3945.79+Safari/537.36 - https://cbwwebdev.azurewebsites.net/login?returnUrl=%2Fdashboard **myURLIDOntWantPublic** 502 3 12029 471 1335 31
2019-12-12 22:05:15 CBWSERVICESDEV OPTIONS /auth/credentials X-ARR-LOG-ID=f6a96a91-25f9-4de8-86ba-9ba1463e2bad 443 - 68.118.135.78 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/79.0.3945.79+Safari/537.36 - https://cbwwebdev.azurewebsites.net/login?returnUrl=%2Fdashboard **myURLIDOntWantPublic** 200 0 0 355 1297 15
2019-12-12 22:05:15 CBWSERVICESDEV POST /auth/credentials X-ARR-LOG-ID=18697ac0-94df-41be-b06a-cc257011ffe5 443 - 68.118.135.78 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/79.0.3945.79+Safari/537.36 - https://cbwwebdev.azurewebsites.net/login?returnUrl=%2Fdashboard **myURLIDOntWantPublic** 502 3 12029 471 1335 20
2019-12-12 22:05:29 CBWSERVICESDEV POST /json/reply/Authenticate X-ARR-LOG-ID=b1223772-bc2f-4f99-9440-09b61efb3619 443 - 104.43.246.4 ServiceStack+.NET+Client+5.60 - - **myURLIDOntWantPublic** 502 3 12029 405 1229 15
2019-12-12 22:05:42 CBWSERVICESDEV POST /auth/credentials username=DevAdmin&password=test1&format=json&X-ARR-LOG-ID=20fae172-e631-48b1-975d-fa0cd7a4a605 443 - 68.118.135.78 PostmanRuntime/7.6.0 ss-id=qJ0iFIYvRCQZUqyvtlPV;+ss-pid=ethhehYdtnTY1n4vBh3J;+ss-opt=perm;+X-UAId=2;+ARRAffinity=bca9cc31b3143085a28e07db54604157e121c61665b54a8ce9a954d588f1a532 - **myURLIDOntWantPublic** 502 3 12029 405 1372 15
2019-12-12 22:05:42 CBWSERVICESDEV GET /Home/Login userName=DevAdmin&password=test1&X-ARR-LOG-ID=ab396a09-dced-497f-9103-4b9fe79f18e1 443 - 68.118.135.78 PostmanRuntime/7.6.0 ss-id=qJ0iFIYvRCQZUqyvtlPV;+ss-pid=ethhehYdtnTY1n4vBh3J;+ss-opt=perm;+X-UAId=2;+ARRAffinity=bca9cc31b3143085a28e07db54604157e121c61665b54a8ce9a954d588f1a532 - **myURLIDOntWantPublic** 502 3 12029 405 1258 15
2019-12-12 22:06:00 CBWSERVICESDEV POST /json/reply/Authenticate X-ARR-LOG-ID=06a80f4e-297d-40a8-ab67-1fc222f45cb0 443 - 104.43.246.4 ServiceStack+.NET+Client+5.60 - - **myURLIDOntWantPublic** 502 3 12029 405 1229 15
2019-12-12 22:06:00 CBWSERVICESDEV POST /json/reply/Authenticate X-ARR-LOG-ID=3de27a9d-a9c5-40b2-9afa-38c485745927 443 - 104.43.246.4 ServiceStack+.NET+Client+5.60 - - **myURLIDOntWantPublic** 502 3 12029 405 1229 31
2019-12-12 22:06:30 CBWSERVICESDEV POST /json/reply/Authenticate X-ARR-LOG-ID=e28d1ce4-f648-476b-878b-84da3ebfbbd7 443 - 104.43.246.4 ServiceStack+.NET+Client+5.60 - - **myURLIDOntWantPublic** 502 3 12029 405 1229 15
2019-12-12 22:06:59 CBWSERVICESDEV POST /json/reply/Authenticate X-ARR-LOG-ID=680f9397-955c-49dd-baea-ba4ed5133d13 443 - 104.43.246.4 ServiceStack+.NET+Client+5.60 - - **myURLIDOntWantPublic** 502 3 12029 405 1229 33
2019-12-12 22:06:59 CBWSERVICESDEV POST /json/reply/Authenticate X-ARR-LOG-ID=1c38adec-07a9-4c66-85e9-c26dc6ebc36d 443 - 104.43.246.4 ServiceStack+.NET+Client+5.60 - - **myURLIDOntWantPublic** 502 3 12029 405 1229 31
2019-12-12 22:07:30 CBWSERVICESDEV POST /json/reply/Authenticate X-ARR-LOG-ID=2a3965e8-c5ae-45d4-8c9c-06790894b0f3 443 - 104.43.246.4 ServiceStack+.NET+Client+5.60 - - **myURLIDOntWantPublic** 502 3 12029 405 1229 46
2019-12-12 22:08:00 CBWSERVICESDEV POST /json/reply/Authenticate X-ARR-LOG-ID=4abd3957-183f-4636-84bf-da8b7eb4b9e0 443 - 104.43.246.4 ServiceStack+.NET+Client+5.60 - - **myURLIDOntWantPublic** 502 3 12029 405 1229 15
2019-12-12 22:08:00 CBWSERVICESDEV POST /json/reply/Authenticate X-ARR-LOG-ID=8b69b6f8-ff4a-41d8-9da0-3224406cb669 443 - 104.43.246.4 ServiceStack+.NET+Client+5.60 - - **myURLIDOntWantPublic** 502 3 12029 405 1229 31
2019-12-12 22:08:30 CBWSERVICESDEV POST /json/reply/Authenticate X-ARR-LOG-ID=7bd72b31-f94f-422f-b23d-dcbf2fdde29e 443 - 104.43.246.4 ServiceStack+.NET+Client+5.60 - - **myURLIDOntWantPublic** 502 3 12029 405 1229 18
2019-12-12 22:09:00 CBWSERVICESDEV POST /json/reply/Authenticate X-ARR-LOG-ID=9c4cd886-5c2c-4c64-ad4d-86b5f830be97 443 - 104.43.246.4 ServiceStack+.NET+Client+5.60 - - **myURLIDOntWantPublic** 502 3 12029 405 1229 31
2019-12-12 22:09:00 CBWSERVICESDEV POST /json/reply/Authenticate X-ARR-LOG-ID=3ba5c516-669b-46fe-8f69-b618cf1b4d34 443 - 104.43.246.4 ServiceStack+.NET+Client+5.60 - - **myURLIDOntWantPublic** 502 3 12029 405 1229 31
2019-12-12 22:09:04 ~1CBWSERVICESDEV GET / - 80 - 10.0.128.27 AlwaysOn - - **myURLIDOntWantPublic** 200 0 0 3107 452 31
2019-12-12 22:09:04 CBWSERVICESDEV GET / X-ARR-LOG-ID=934c9e9f-774e-45d7-a82f-4784cefd0f1f 80 - ::1 AlwaysOn ARRAffinity=bca9cc31b3143085a28e07db54604157e121c61665b54a8ce9a954d588f1a532 - **myURLIDOntWantPublic** 502 3 12029 405 694 15
2019-12-12 22:09:29 CBWSERVICESDEV POST /json/reply/Authenticate X-ARR-LOG-ID=c2227d5b-6da8-4386-a02a-ef953c0d92bc 443 - 104.43.246.4 ServiceStack+.NET+Client+5.60 - - **myURLIDOntWantPublic** 502 3 12029 405 1229 15
2019-12-12 22:09:59 CBWSERVICESDEV POST /json/reply/Authenticate X-ARR-LOG-ID=a7b37f00-14f4-4087-8311-a91a1836d20f 443 - 104.43.246.4 ServiceStack+.NET+Client+5.60 - - **myURLIDOntWantPublic** 502 3 12029 405 1229 15
2019-12-12 22:09:59 CBWSERVICESDEV POST /json/reply/Authenticate X-ARR-LOG-ID=e432a310-e895-4026-9fd8-03c1d3526e73 443 - 104.43.246.4 ServiceStack+.NET+Client+5.60 - - **myURLIDOntWantPublic** 502 3 12029 405 1229 31
2019-12-12 22:10:30 CBWSERVICESDEV POST /json/reply/Authenticate X-ARR-LOG-ID=b5ecd0eb-99a1-49b8-9977-edd981655903 443 - 104.43.246.4 ServiceStack+.NET+Client+5.60 - - **myURLIDOntWantPublic** 502 3 12029 405 1229 36
2019-12-12 22:11:00 CBWSERVICESDEV POST /json/reply/Authenticate X-ARR-LOG-ID=29565513-1747-49e4-ba6e-6477c36e9b91 443 - 104.43.246.4 ServiceStack+.NET+Client+5.60 - - **myURLIDOntWantPublic** 502 3 12029 405 1229 10
2019-12-12 22:11:00 CBWSERVICESDEV POST /json/reply/Authenticate X-ARR-LOG-ID=1f86d835-e667-4eda-9793-c0f9bb0db771 443 - 104.43.246.4 ServiceStack+.NET+Client+5.60 - - **myURLIDOntWantPublic** 502 3 12029 405 1229 31
2019-12-12 22:11:29 CBWSERVICESDEV POST /json/reply/Authenticate X-ARR-LOG-ID=05d56e17-2679-431e-94b8-ab4043e77d53 443 - 104.43.246.4 ServiceStack+.NET+Client+5.60 - - **myURLIDOntWantPublic** 502 3 12029 405 1229 15
2019-12-12 22:11:59 CBWSERVICESDEV POST /json/reply/Authenticate X-ARR-LOG-ID=0736f250-425e-457d-a67e-d453c1604f71 443 - 104.43.246.4 ServiceStack+.NET+Client+5.60 - - **myURLIDOntWantPublic** 502 3 12029 405 1229 31
2019-12-12 22:11:59 CBWSERVICESDEV POST /json/reply/Authenticate X-ARR-LOG-ID=caa19b61-5c5a-44aa-af17-d6cb3d45891a 443 - 104.43.246.4 ServiceStack+.NET+Client+5.60 - - **myURLIDOntWantPublic** 502 3 12029 405 1229 27
2019-12-12 22:11:59 CBWSERVICESDEV POST /json/reply/Authenticate X-ARR-LOG-ID=3ee39293-78a9-472a-aec2-77dd1620c023 443 - 104.43.246.4 ServiceStack+.NET+Client+5.60 - - **myURLIDOntWantPublic** 502 3 12029 405 1229 27
2019-12-12 22:12:30 CBWSERVICESDEV POST /json/reply/Authenticate X-ARR-LOG-ID=68c8d6b1-f371-4328-87c9-afa99767ec12 443 - 104.43.246.4 ServiceStack+.NET+Client+5.60 - - **myURLIDOntWantPublic** 502 3 12029 405 1229 46
2019-12-12 22:12:30 CBWSERVICESDEV POST /json/reply/Authenticate X-ARR-LOG-ID=0c65398f-83d6-4622-8000-89f088c30a1c 443 - 104.43.246.4 ServiceStack+.NET+Client+5.60 - - **myURLIDOntWantPublic** 502 3 12029 405 1229 15
2019-12-12 22:12:59 CBWSERVICESDEV POST /json/reply/Authenticate X-ARR-LOG-ID=cf9390c8-34c7-48a2-8267-979d2a04dd0d 443 - 104.43.246.4 ServiceStack+.NET+Client+5.60 - - **myURLIDOntWantPublic** 502 3 12029 405 1229 20
2019-12-12 22:12:59 CBWSERVICESDEV POST /json/reply/Authenticate X-ARR-LOG-ID=3086f707-b055-45ea-b636-c9966d02d660 443 - 104.43.246.4 ServiceStack+.NET+Client+5.60 - - **myURLIDOntWantPublic** 502 3 12029 405 1229 27
2019-12-12 22:13:30 CBWSERVICESDEV POST /json/reply/Authenticate X-ARR-LOG-ID=f7b5126b-43f0-440f-b876-91e1e2b7187d 443 - 104.43.246.4 ServiceStack+.NET+Client+5.60 - - **myURLIDOntWantPublic** 502 3 12029 405 1229 31
2019-12-12 22:14:00 CBWSERVICESDEV POST /json/reply/Authenticate X-ARR-LOG-ID=f12c56c2-fe22-4472-8100-62747305fe44 443 - 104.43.246.4 ServiceStack+.NET+Client+5.60 - - **myURLIDOntWantPublic** 502 3 12029 405 1229 18
2019-12-12 22:14:00 CBWSERVICESDEV POST /json/reply/Authenticate X-ARR-LOG-ID=8794002a-ebf6-4a04-89b1-452aea682a24 443 - 104.43.246.4 ServiceStack+.NET+Client+5.60 - - **myURLIDOntWantPublic** 502 3 12029 405 1229 31
2019-12-12 22:14:04 ~1CBWSERVICESDEV GET / - 80 - 10.0.128.27 AlwaysOn - - **myURLIDOntWantPublic** 200 0 0 3107 452 31
2019-12-12 22:14:04 CBWSERVICESDEV GET / X-ARR-LOG-ID=88de1c01-96db-4c13-9cf1-661597788541 80 - ::1 AlwaysOn ARRAffinity=bca9cc31b3143085a28e07db54604157e121c61665b54a8ce9a954d588f1a532 - **myURLIDOntWantPublic** 502 3 12029 405 694 34
2019-12-12 22:14:29 CBWSERVICESDEV POST /json/reply/Authenticate X-ARR-LOG-ID=0b0d187a-ab2f-4a74-891b-6d96065606e6 443 - 104.43.246.4 ServiceStack+.NET+Client+5.60 - - **myURLIDOntWantPublic** 502 3 12029 405 1229 15
2019-12-12 22:14:59 CBWSERVICESDEV POST /json/reply/Authenticate X-ARR-LOG-ID=dccd1cea-b723-4aed-9c6a-038394f4b9df 443 - 104.43.246.4 ServiceStack+.NET+Client+5.60 - - **myURLIDOntWantPublic** 502 3 12029 405 1229 31
2019-12-12 22:14:59 CBWSERVICESDEV POST /json/reply/Authenticate X-ARR-LOG-ID=55d1dc2f-1af4-45e2-bab4-33d68137a786 443 - 104.43.246.4 ServiceStack+.NET+Client+5.60 - - **myURLIDOntWantPublic** 502 3 12029 405 1229 15
2019-12-12 22:15:30 CBWSERVICESDEV POST /json/reply/Authenticate X-ARR-LOG-ID=879955e0-ba75-4259-b603-b204c4acc429 443 - 104.43.246.4 ServiceStack+.NET+Client+5.60 - - **myURLIDOntWantPublic** 502 3 12029 405 1229 31
2019-12-12 22:16:00 CBWSERVICESDEV POST /json/reply/Authenticate X-ARR-LOG-ID=4ab7b484-ed45-453d-8eae-b1c55261bbbd 443 - 104.43.246.4 ServiceStack+.NET+Client+5.60 - - **myURLIDOntWantPublic** 502 3 12029 405 1229 18
2019-12-12 22:16:00 CBWSERVICESDEV POST /json/reply/Authenticate X-ARR-LOG-ID=40e059fa-22ec-4fed-9ee0-67ae42790a24 443 - 104.43.246.4 ServiceStack+.NET+Client+5.60 - - **myURLIDOntWantPublic** 502 3 12029 405 1229 31
2019-12-12 22:16:30 CBWSERVICESDEV POST /json/reply/Authenticate X-ARR-LOG-ID=4f950b3e-57b9-471d-97e6-f18d5ff1e50c 443 - 104.43.246.4 ServiceStack+.NET+Client+5.60 - - **myURLIDOntWantPublic** 502 3 12029 405 1229 15
2019-12-12 22:16:59 CBWSERVICESDEV POST /json/reply/Authenticate X-ARR-LOG-ID=eaeacda2-5889-4773-83e3-fb649546e816 443 - 104.43.246.4 ServiceStack+.NET+Client+5.60 - - **myURLIDOntWantPublic** 502 3 12029 405 1229 18
2019-12-12 22:16:59 CBWSERVICESDEV POST /json/reply/Authenticate X-ARR-LOG-ID=98fdd917-b513-49d8-8562-ec38d6a67f24 443 - 104.43.246.4 ServiceStack+.NET+Client+5.60 - - **myURLIDOntWantPublic** 502 3 12029 405 1229 31
2019-12-12 22:17:30 CBWSERVICESDEV POST /json/reply/Authenticate X-ARR-LOG-ID=fb8ed8c7-c211-4968-bc86-2cb48a9dc1c0 443 - 104.43.246.4 ServiceStack+.NET+Client+5.60 - - **myURLIDOntWantPublic** 502 3 12029 405 1229 15
2019-12-12 22:18:00 CBWSERVICESDEV POST /json/reply/Authenticate X-ARR-LOG-ID=b3b1afbf-087e-4297-b382-3ac39f2934a8 443 - 104.43.246.4 ServiceStack+.NET+Client+5.60 - - **myURLIDOntWantPublic** 502 3 12029 405 1229 18
2019-12-12 22:18:00 CBWSERVICESDEV POST /json/reply/Authenticate X-ARR-LOG-ID=576fb84a-d091-4226-b1fe-8014782437de 443 - 104.43.246.4 ServiceStack+.NET+Client+5.60 - - **myURLIDOntWantPublic** 502 3 12029 405 1229 31
2019-12-12 22:18:30 CBWSERVICESDEV POST /json/reply/Authenticate X-ARR-LOG-ID=7d7c108a-9b4b-4ce4-9393-ff622b760b8c 443 - 104.43.246.4 ServiceStack+.NET+Client+5.60 - - **myURLIDOntWantPublic** 502 3 12029 405 1229 15
2019-12-12 22:18:59 CBWSERVICESDEV POST /json/reply/Authenticate X-ARR-LOG-ID=622152b8-e507-40ba-93ed-a7eb755513f8 443 - 104.43.246.4 ServiceStack+.NET+Client+5.60 - - **myURLIDOntWantPublic** 502 3 12029 405 1229 18
2019-12-12 22:18:59 CBWSERVICESDEV POST /json/reply/Authenticate X-ARR-LOG-ID=3afa4b6c-6885-4215-8aa7-207128ce4621 443 - 104.43.246.4 ServiceStack+.NET+Client+5.60 - - **myURLIDOntWantPublic** 502 3 12029 405 1229 31
2019-12-12 22:19:03 ~1CBWSERVICESDEV GET / - 80 - 10.0.128.27 AlwaysOn - - **myURLIDOntWantPublic** 200 0 0 3108 452 31
2019-12-12 22:19:03 CBWSERVICESDEV GET / X-ARR-LOG-ID=84446b09-5895-46ce-86a1-2df514dca994 80 - ::1 AlwaysOn ARRAffinity=bca9cc31b3143085a28e07db54604157e121c61665b54a8ce9a954d588f1a532 - **myURLIDOntWantPublic** 502 3 12029 405 694 43
2019-12-12 22:19:30 CBWSERVICESDEV POST /json/reply/Authenticate X-ARR-LOG-ID=62c46788-917f-4488-b925-c3c67997c073 443 - 104.43.246.4 ServiceStack+.NET+Client+5.60 - - **myURLIDOntWantPublic** 502 3 12029 405 1229 31
2019-12-12 22:19:59 CBWSERVICESDEV POST /json/reply/Authenticate X-ARR-LOG-ID=3b6ae63a-9cf9-4f1c-b249-1653c2da95c9 443 - 104.43.246.4 ServiceStack+.NET+Client+5.60 - - **myURLIDOntWantPublic** 502 3 12029 405 1229 9
2019-12-12 22:19:59 CBWSERVICESDEV POST /json/reply/Authenticate X-ARR-LOG-ID=a305cf3a-0940-4b2f-abf2-1a712357beeb 443 - 104.43.246.4 ServiceStack+.NET+Client+5.60 - - **myURLIDOntWantPublic** 502 3 12029 405 1229 0
2019-12-12 22:20:30 CBWSERVICESDEV POST /json/reply/Authenticate X-ARR-LOG-ID=9b2179bf-dc79-4416-97cf-cd1f9b75b3b0 443 - 104.43.246.4 ServiceStack+.NET+Client+5.60 - - **myURLIDOntWantPublic** 502 3 12029 405 1229 60
2019-12-12 22:21:00 CBWSERVICESDEV POST /json/reply/Authenticate X-ARR-LOG-ID=1f5ba30e-4eb1-4d6a-bdc0-040d7b30ce1c 443 - 104.43.246.4 ServiceStack+.NET+Client+5.60 - - **myURLIDOntWantPublic** 502 3 12029 405 1229 13
2019-12-12 22:21:00 CBWSERVICESDEV POST /json/reply/Authenticate X-ARR-LOG-ID=8d6533a5-74bc-4ba4-8e8f-342d8604e874 443 - 104.43.246.4 ServiceStack+.NET+Client+5.60 - - **myURLIDOntWantPublic** 502 3 12029 405 1229 28
2019-12-12 22:21:30 CBWSERVICESDEV POST /json/reply/Authenticate X-ARR-LOG-ID=d8b88045-f36d-45ef-ba8c-b5278a88d2c4 443 - 104.43.246.4 ServiceStack+.NET+Client+5.60 - - **myURLIDOntWantPublic** 502 3 12029 405 1229 31
2019-12-12 22:22:00 CBWSERVICESDEV POST /json/reply/Authenticate X-ARR-LOG-ID=d599d866-9273-4e5f-b8dc-b48703315e51 443 - 104.43.246.4 ServiceStack+.NET+Client+5.60 - - **myURLIDOntWantPublic** 502 3 12029 405 1229 13
2019-12-12 22:22:00 CBWSERVICESDEV POST /json/reply/Authenticate X-ARR-LOG-ID=c63c1650-7e3a-47b1-9e90-e3d179afc356 443 - 104.43.246.4 ServiceStack+.NET+Client+5.60 - - **myURLIDOntWantPublic** 502 3 12029 405 1229 29
2019-12-12 22:22:00 CBWSERVICESDEV POST /json/reply/Authenticate X-ARR-LOG-ID=0a454458-cdd0-4fa0-8637-78b056d96a68 443 - 104.43.246.4 ServiceStack+.NET+Client+5.60 - - **myURLIDOntWantPublic** 502 3 12029 405 1229 50
2019-12-12 22:22:17 CBWSERVICESDEV OPTIONS /auth/credentials X-ARR-LOG-ID=9b6643ae-a431-4e43-bb8f-c043cb052866 443 - 68.118.135.78 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/79.0.3945.79+Safari/537.36 - https://cbwwebdev.azurewebsites.net/login?returnUrl=%2Fdashboard **myURLIDOntWantPublic** 200 0 0 355 1297 0
2019-12-12 22:22:17 CBWSERVICESDEV POST /auth/credentials X-ARR-LOG-ID=da619369-b941-48bc-99af-ea59c94127af 443 - 68.118.135.78 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/79.0.3945.79+Safari/537.36 - https://cbwwebdev.azurewebsites.net/login?returnUrl=%2Fdashboard **myURLIDOntWantPublic** 502 3 12029 471 1335 15
2019-12-12 22:22:18 CBWSERVICESDEV POST /auth/credentials X-ARR-LOG-ID=1ee0b4ec-e14a-45f6-8993-b92aecfc4935 443 - 68.118.135.78 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/79.0.3945.79+Safari/537.36 - https://cbwwebdev.azurewebsites.net/login?returnUrl=%2Fdashboard **myURLIDOntWantPublic** 502 3 12029 471 1335 15
2019-12-12 22:22:20 CBWSERVICESDEV POST /auth/credentials X-ARR-LOG-ID=994d01de-54ec-4b43-9e96-b1caa0b51dd7 443 - 68.118.135.78 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/79.0.3945.79+Safari/537.36 - https://cbwwebdev.azurewebsites.net/login?returnUrl=%2Fdashboard **myURLIDOntWantPublic** 502 3 12029 471 1335 18
2019-12-12 22:22:23 CBWSERVICESDEV OPTIONS /auth/credentials X-ARR-LOG-ID=06292235-df2e-4e69-a6e5-a8aa10b22597 443 - 68.118.135.78 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/79.0.3945.79+Safari/537.36 - https://cbwwebdev.azurewebsites.net/login?returnUrl=%2Fdashboard **myURLIDOntWantPublic** 200 0 0 355 1297 33
2019-12-12 22:22:23 CBWSERVICESDEV POST /auth/credentials X-ARR-LOG-ID=c53f6836-8f0b-441b-a8f1-564ab3ab548d 443 - 68.118.135.78 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/79.0.3945.79+Safari/537.36 - https://cbwwebdev.azurewebsites.net/login?returnUrl=%2Fdashboard **myURLIDOntWantPublic** 502 3 12029 471 1335 15
2019-12-12 22:22:30 CBWSERVICESDEV POST /json/reply/Authenticate X-ARR-LOG-ID=ee6a7f7a-59e5-4492-9464-9214200e1056 443 - 104.43.246.4 ServiceStack+.NET+Client+5.60 - - **myURLIDOntWantPublic** 502 3 12029 405 1229 16
2019-12-12 22:22:59 CBWSERVICESDEV POST /json/reply/Authenticate X-ARR-LOG-ID=62d4e790-0996-43d8-ac8c-d8c792c648b0 443 - 104.43.246.4 ServiceStack+.NET+Client+5.60 - - **myURLIDOntWantPublic** 502 3 12029 405 1229 31
2019-12-12 22:22:59 CBWSERVICESDEV POST /json/reply/Authenticate X-ARR-LOG-ID=d3842790-4aa0-47c9-8164-fa2893017035 443 - 104.43.246.4 ServiceStack+.NET+Client+5.60 - - **myURLIDOntWantPublic** 502 3 12029 405 1229 31
2019-12-12 22:23:30 CBWSERVICESDEV POST /json/reply/Authenticate X-ARR-LOG-ID=740ae489-4db3-4399-b3d5-841f20b08746 443 - 104.43.246.4 ServiceStack+.NET+Client+5.60 - - **myURLIDOntWantPublic** 502 3 12029 405 1229 28
2019-12-12 22:24:00 CBWSERVICESDEV POST /json/reply/Authenticate X-ARR-LOG-ID=7daed7c1-057c-44cc-bf28-9b4a056ee95f 443 - 104.43.246.4 ServiceStack+.NET+Client+5.60 - - **myURLIDOntWantPublic** 502 3 12029 405 1229 15
2019-12-12 22:24:00 CBWSERVICESDEV POST /json/reply/Authenticate X-ARR-LOG-ID=f9ba6ce2-3123-43ff-88d9-7f34eabdeacc 443 - 104.43.246.4 ServiceStack+.NET+Client+5.60 - - **myURLIDOntWantPublic** 502 3 12029 405 1229 26
2019-12-12 22:24:04 CBWSERVICESDEV OPTIONS /auth/credentials X-ARR-LOG-ID=eef13f99-7faa-4aaa-b648-26493afc96ae 443 - 68.118.135.78 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/79.0.3945.79+Safari/537.36 - https://cbwwebdev.azurewebsites.net/login?returnUrl=%2Fdashboard **myURLIDOntWantPublic** 200 0 0 355 1297 15
2019-12-12 22:24:04 ~1CBWSERVICESDEV GET / - 80 - 10.0.128.27 AlwaysOn - - **myURLIDOntWantPublic** 200 0 0 3106 452 48
2019-12-12 22:24:04 CBWSERVICESDEV POST /auth/credentials X-ARR-LOG-ID=f66cdccf-a5b9-4be5-b471-1cb07a2b687a 443 - 68.118.135.78 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/79.0.3945.79+Safari/537.36 - https://cbwwebdev.azurewebsites.net/login?returnUrl=%2Fdashboard **myURLIDOntWantPublic** 502 3 12029 471 1335 35
2019-12-12 22:24:04 CBWSERVICESDEV GET / X-ARR-LOG-ID=8199d9d3-bd23-4107-bfa2-826cad3573ac 80 - ::1 AlwaysOn ARRAffinity=bca9cc31b3143085a28e07db54604157e121c61665b54a8ce9a954d588f1a532 - **myURLIDOntWantPublic** 502 3 12029 405 696 46
2019-12-12 22:24:05 CBWSERVICESDEV POST /auth/credentials X-ARR-LOG-ID=3d5faacc-6451-4735-9e1a-438abd2c0927 443 - 68.118.135.78 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/79.0.3945.79+Safari/537.36 - https://cbwwebdev.azurewebsites.net/login?returnUrl=%2Fdashboard **myURLIDOntWantPublic** 502 3 12029 471 1335 15
2019-12-12 22:24:08 CBWSERVICESDEV POST /auth/credentials X-ARR-LOG-ID=6f3b7031-dc7e-4ebf-b985-5a0f9a7a373e 443 - 68.118.135.78 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/79.0.3945.79+Safari/537.36 - https://cbwwebdev.azurewebsites.net/login?returnUrl=%2Fdashboard **myURLIDOntWantPublic** 502 3 12029 471 1335 31
2019-12-12 22:24:11 CBWSERVICESDEV OPTIONS /auth/credentials X-ARR-LOG-ID=ba9b4b73-43a9-49c9-874b-63b47f1e2ab7 443 - 68.118.135.78 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/79.0.3945.79+Safari/537.36 - https://cbwwebdev.azurewebsites.net/login?returnUrl=%2Fdashboard **myURLIDOntWantPublic** 200 0 0 355 1297 15
2019-12-12 22:24:11 CBWSERVICESDEV POST /auth/credentials X-ARR-LOG-ID=72d61c3d-7793-4aba-ac6e-da0916501f5a 443 - 68.118.135.78 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/79.0.3945.79+Safari/537.36 - https://cbwwebdev.azurewebsites.net/login?returnUrl=%2Fdashboard **myURLIDOntWantPublic** 502 3 12029 471 1335 20
2019-12-12 22:24:30 CBWSERVICESDEV POST /json/reply/Authenticate X-ARR-LOG-ID=c87a46b6-e4d5-4831-a8e8-b24e8d7a9a77 443 - 104.43.246.4 ServiceStack+.NET+Client+5.60 - - **myURLIDOntWantPublic** 502 3 12029 405 1229 15
2019-12-12 22:24:59 CBWSERVICESDEV POST /json/reply/Authenticate X-ARR-LOG-ID=a738bb22-6ef2-4f20-80ec-6dec68ebaaf5 443 - 104.43.246.4 ServiceStack+.NET+Client+5.60 - - **myURLIDOntWantPublic** 502 3 12029 405 1229 18
2019-12-12 22:24:59 CBWSERVICESDEV POST /json/reply/Authenticate X-ARR-LOG-ID=f780db61-76e8-4db2-92d0-5d51e6c80f6b 443 - 104.43.246.4 ServiceStack+.NET+Client+5.60 - - **myURLIDOntWantPublic** 502 3 12029 405 1229 31
2019-12-12 22:25:30 CBWSERVICESDEV POST /json/reply/Authenticate X-ARR-LOG-ID=1132ae72-4968-4b99-b3bd-499b745f6f3f 443 - 104.43.246.4 ServiceStack+.NET+Client+5.60 - - **myURLIDOntWantPublic** 502 3 12029 405 1229 46
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [502 is a gateway error](https://www.lifewire.com/502-bad-gateway-error-explained-2622939) meaning the downstream proxied server returned an invalid HTTP response, you won’t be able to identify the issue from your external requests, you’ll need to investigate the issue in the App, e.g. through App Error logs. I’m not familiar with what Azure tools have to help diagnose this, typically I’d SSH into the server and make a local request and inspect the HTTP Response to identify the issue.

Comment: I ended up deleting the app service environment and redeploying it. and we deployed a few other changes to how we logout users. It does not appear to be happening now.  Very odd, but at this point Ill chalk it up to Azure, not ServiceStack

Comment: @SteveColeman I'm assuming they're the gateway/proxy logs as they're the only ones that's going to be returning a 502 gateway error. You need the error logs of your actual App (i.e. the downstream server). If the `405` in the logs refers to the downstream Status Code, the ServiceStack will return a `405 Method Not Allowed` for any `NotImplementedException` or `NotSupportedException` Exceptions. If you're using a custom AuthProvider I'd look to see if it's throwing those exceptions anywhere.

Comment: I am closing this one. it's not servicestack. Its clearly azure or .netcore thanks!

Comment: So I figured out what is actually causing it and re-posted to hopefully find a resolution. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59337413/azure-netcore-appservice-locks-up-sending-503s-becuase-of-aync-calls